# NP-Hard on Complete Graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete, np-hard

I have a problem (A) on undirected graphs that I wish to show is NP-Hard. I can show that there is a reduction from a well known NP-Hard problem (B) to A by constructing an instance of A *with a complete graph* that solves B.

Since undirected graphs generalize complete graphs, am I safe in saying that A is NP-Hard for undirected graphs? Something about that doesn't seem right to me, since problem A on complete graphs is essentially the "non-graphical" version of the problem. Am I missing something?

Disclaimer: I am new to proving hardness results.

Comment: You aren’t missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when reducing problem B to problem A, not all possible instances of problem A appear in the image of the reduction. This is absolutely not an issue.

In your case, you can say that problem A is NP-hard even if restricted only to complete graphs. This is a stronger result, which is a good thing, and definitely allowed.

As an example, 3-coloring is hard even for 4-colorable graphs, and even just for planar graphs. You show this (say) by reduction from SAT to 3-coloring, in which all the resulting graphs are planar. This is not a drawback – in fact it's a bonus.